Run Android instrumental test against a build type, not a flavor
My Android application has 3 build types: debug, instrument, and release. Build types debug and release are quite typical, however, my custom instrument build type has some secrets injected into it, so I can easily access them in Espresso using BuildConfig.SECRETKEY. I share debug .apk files with testers quite frequently, and I don't want them to have the means to disassemble the app and gain access to BuildConfig.SECRETKEY, so that's why I created an instrumental target. So far, I have been unable to run the tests using Gradle. I tried setting testBuildType = "instrument" and renaming the test directory from androidTest to androidTestInstrument as suggested here, but to no avail, neither Android Studio nor Gradle recognizes it as a valid test folder. Do you have any suggestions on how to work around the issue or resolve it and run the tests on instrument?
